# Docco not working as advertised

Tags: node.js, documentation, coffeescript, requirejs, docco

I'm trying to use [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/) to auto-document my coffeescript. In the example below, the comments get output properly. But the code is not given in the output on the right-pane... Just "***undefined***" as output. Now, I've double-checked, and I've already installed the pre-requisite packages: Node.js, Pygments, and CoffeeScript.

ex: thing.coffee

```
    # #Header One 
    # ## Sub-Header
    #
    # > Some block quote
    asdf = 1

    # # Another Header
    # * my list
    # * second item
    qwerty = "aa": "bbb"
```

The only thing I can think of is that pygments isn't outputting the correct thing. This is the feedback I get from [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/):

```
    $ docco thing.coffee 
    %ltBuffer 45 72 72 6f 72 3a%gt
    %ltBuffer 20%gt
    %ltBuffer 6e 6f 20 6c 65 78 65 72 20 66 6f 72 20 61 6c 69 61 73 20 27 63 6f 66 66 65 65 2d 73 63 72 69 70 74 27 20 66 6f 75 6e 64 0a%gt
    docco: thing.coffee -> docs/thing.html
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code here and it works fine. When I run docco it only outputs the last line, so most likely there is something wrong with the dependencies that docco uses.

Comment: It turns out that I didn't have python's pygments installed. I had to run `sudo easy_install pygments`. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/1476877) lays it out.